# How to discern the location of a file/tab in Microsoft Teams from the tab's URL

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I have a situation where someone has added a tab to a team in Microsoft Teams, and the tab appears to lead to a file... except the file is not one that is hosted/stored within that Team. The issue is that no one in the team appears to have access to the file, including the owners.

There are no documents in the team's Files folder or the team's SharePoint site's Documents folder (or any other folders) that match the name of the file link or that have unique permissions (in other words, all team members/owners have access to all the files uploaded to the team itself).

When I copy the tab's URL, Teams frustratingly hides the actual file URL (e.g. a SharePoint or OneDrive URL, like I expected) with an esoteric Teams-specific URL:

`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/1c256a65-3333-2222-1111-123412341234/_djb2_msteams_prefix_792457649?context={"channelId":"19:a7d8031d133243a7aabc9ffdfc75b94f@thread.tacv2"}&groupId=4263c38e-333-2222-1111-333322221111&tenantId=e80adaf3-3333-2222-1111-123412341234`

<sub>(the GUIDs have been modified in the above URL for security reasons)</sub>

Is there a way I can tell (e.g. from the Teams Admin Center or via PowerShell) from the URL above where that given URL points to/where that file is located?

Comment: Does this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/files/do-not-have-access-to-this-file-teams) explain the problem?

Comment: @harrymc No it does not. The problem is I cannot find where the file is located--once I find it, I can solve the permissions issue. This is also not a classic SharePoint site-it's a modern team site created automatically via the creation of a team in Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I looked a little too deep for a solution. If you try to open the file which isn't currently shared, Teams will present you with an option to request access:

[image: screenshot of the 'request access' option in Microsoft Teams]

If you open the team in a web browser, highlighting the 'Request Access' button will show the URL at the bottom corner of the window. Alternatively, simply clicking the button will take you to a web page to request access.

Once I realized that, I was able to copy the *real* (sharepoint.com) URL to the file location, and I found that the file no longer existed (the URL showed a 404 error). Luckily, in my case, a user of the team had deleted the file recently, so it was still in the Team site's Recycle Bin. Once I restored the file, the issue was resolved.